# Flutter show image with network url directly form Firestore is very slow

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I am storing Firestore image url in my db and fetch directly form flutter app. It is very slow even compare with image hosting on DO's 6$ per month server. It took me nearly one minute to show the images. Is there anyway to improve the speed?

https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myproject.appspot.com/o/images%2Falbums%2Fchin%20thae%20lae%20pyan.jpg?alt=media&token=9966803a-d4a7-4686-a0c2-8f5367bc89f6

```
Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      image: NetworkImage(album.albumCover),
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                    child: Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                      //padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100)),
                      child: const Icon(
                        Icons.play_arrow,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello you need can use CachedNetworkImage instead of NetworkImage refer below

[CachedNetworkImage](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image)

```
CachedNetworkImage(
      imageUrl: "your_image_url",
      imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) => Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
              image: imageProvider,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
      errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
    ),
```

let me know if you have any query

Comment: Thanks. It is faster then Networkimage, Cached is working for second time.

Comment: @AlexAung Great! Happy Coding!